# Binding the same interface twice (Guice)

Tags: java, class, dependency-injection, interface, guice

My classes (let call them `X` and `Y`) both implementing `Parser` interface do (relatively) CPU intensive operations to build parsers for certain syntaxes (different syntaxes for `X` and `Y`).

Now I want to inject (with Guice) dependencies of both `X` and `Y` into constructor of an (upper level) parser `P`. Both arguments of `P` should be of the type `Parser`:

```
class P implements Parser {

    @Inject
    public P(Parser x, Parser y) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

How can I make Guice to differentiate which of the two arguments of `P` shall receive `X` and `Y`?

As you understand, `X` and `Y` should be annotated `@Singleton` (but this note seems unrelated with the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Named](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/inject/Named.html) annotation like this:

```
class P implements Parser {

    @Inject
    public P(@Named("x") Parser x, @Named("y") Parser y) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

in Guice config assign every named variable to his own implementation class

```
bind(Parser.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("x"))
        .to(ParserXImplementation.class);

bind(Parser.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("y"))
        .to(ParserYImplementation.class);
```